# Python gmail API many errors

Tags: python

I have set up the gmail API and have credentials and token in the same directory however whenever I try

```
import ezgmail
ezgmail.init()
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/myPC/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/ezgmail/__init__.py", line 471, in init
    creds = store.get()
  File "/Users/myPC/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 407, in get
    return self.locked_get()
  File "/Users/myPC/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/oauth2client/file.py", line 54, in locked_get
    credentials = client.Credentials.new_from_json(content)
  File "/Users/myPC/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 304, in new_from_json
    module_obj = __import__(module_name)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'module_name' referenced before assignment
```

I've searched many threads but can't find anything that works.
Help please!

Comment: It's interesting that it's failing inside oauth2client. do you have all the required modules installed? I would probably try reinstalling (maybe in a venv) to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Looks like the [dependency oauth2client is deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/oauth2client/). you should reach out to the developer of ezgmail to have them correct this for you.

Comment: Check out this [issue on the ezgmail repo](https://github.com/asweigart/ezgmail/issues/31#issuecomment-859535450) It seems pretty similar to what you're experiencing.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth I tried it but it did not work

Comment: @DavidCulbreth Also, who is the developer?

Comment: They'll be listed on the repo.